# Celery get task results in main thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I'm using Celery connected to a RabbitMQ queue, this queue is filled on a server and proceeded on another one.

I want to get every results from the tasks executed on workers without a backend.

Example:

```
from celery import Celery
import tasks

# Initialize Celery
app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyam')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
    # I wan't to get all the results here with something like that:
    while True:
        app.results.get()
```

Is they any way to do this or at least to get the results inside this program instead of the program who added the task to RabbitMQ ?

I could also put the results in a database or a queue and consume them but if possible I would like to avoid this.

Thanks in advance for all you answers

Answer (score 0):

You could try inspecting the workers in the queue as described [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html?highlight=revoke#inspecting-workers)!

```
# Inspect all nodes.
i = app.control.inspect()

# Specify multiple nodes to inspect.
i = app.control.inspect(['worker1.example.com',
                        'worker2.example.com'])

# Specify a single node to inspect.
i = app.control.inspect('worker1.example.com')
```

Comment: Thanks to this I'm able to see scheduled task and currently running tasks but no't to get all the results. One solution would be to spam the active call to get all the id and use celery.result.AsyncResult(id) but this would be very dirty and I might risk to miss some tasks :/